# ¿Por qué tengo que actualizar dos veces el formulario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando calcular la cantidad de un campo en especifico, pero cuando envío el formulario, este no se actualiza, tengo que darle editar nuevamente y enviarlo para que funcione, esto me pasa cuando elimino los elementos existentes en la compra.

Son atributos `accepts_nested_attributes_for` `ItemCompra` del modelo `Compra`

Modelo Compra

```
class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :item_compras, :dependent => :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras, 
 reject_if: RejectDeeplyNested.blank?,
 :allow_destroy => true

 before_save :calcula_total_bidones

 private

 def calcula_total_bidones
   self.total_bidones = item_compras.map(&:cantidad_bidon).sum
 end

end
```

El modelo `ItemCompra` mantiene una relación `belongs_to`

Simplemente es calcular el `total_bidones`(compra) del valor `cantidad_bidon(item_compra)` creados a partir de la orden de compra, puede ser uno, como pueden ser 10 o más.

**EDICIÓN:** Al actualizar los valores ingresados con anterioridad y actualizar el `total_bidones` no presenta problema, pero al eliminar los elementos `item_compra` desde el formulario de edición de `compra`, no se actualiza el `total_biones`, ***si ya no existen elementos***, este debería quedar en 0.

**EDICIÓN N° 2:** He agregado los logs de la consola, que muestra el registro Active Record.

**Al crear una nueva compra con elementos item_compra**

```
Started POST "/compras" for ::1 at 2017-07-17 06:09:14 -0400
Processing by ComprasController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pXBg2czUb5ZPGYM+izALlsLLXLa2koP0AizLSU6kP5aI3GgMtPV5n8mwwuUQP9k5qMUcys32tz1zyyuihLjlzQ==", "compra"=>{"total_bidones"=>"", "item_compras_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"15", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"20", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Compra"}
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "compras" ("total_bidones", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["total_bidones", 45], ["created_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.273013"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.273013"]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "item_compras" ("cantidad_bidon", "compra_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cantidad_bidon", 10], ["compra_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.281014"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.281014"]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "item_compras" ("cantidad_bidon", "compra_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cantidad_bidon", 15], ["compra_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.287014"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.287014"]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "item_compras" ("cantidad_bidon", "compra_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cantidad_bidon", 20], ["compra_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.293014"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:09:14.293014"]]
   (5.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/compras/3
Completed 302 Found in 53ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
```

**Log al agregar nuevos item_compra a la compra existente**

```
Started PATCH "/compras/3" for ::1 at 2017-07-17 06:10:01 -0400
Processing by ComprasController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pvSqcYNc0fC7nXvHyOyOKM1rSdlWeeiQS73JbkXXnVOLWKKk+33H+T00OhxT41yHp2UJpS0d3Fk6WimFj8tHCA==", "compra"=>{"total_bidones"=>"45", "item_compras_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"8"}, "1"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"15", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"9"}, "2"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"20", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"10"}, "1500286195695"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"80", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Compra", "id"=>"3"}
  Compra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ItemCompra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ? AND "item_compras"."id" IN (8, 9, 10)  [["compra_id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "compras" SET "total_bidones" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "compras"."id" = ?  [["total_bidones", 125], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:10:01.372707"], ["id", 3]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "item_compras" ("cantidad_bidon", "compra_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["cantidad_bidon", 80], ["compra_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-07-17 10:10:01.398709"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:10:01.398709"]]
   (7.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/compras/3
Completed 302 Found in 215ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)
```

**Log al eliminar todos los item_compra de la compra**

```
Started PATCH "/compras/3" for ::1 at 2017-07-17 06:11:26 -0400
Processing by ComprasController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Arq47vVZo19a51sE7MHmCzDtUPL45mmfzcbLZ4H509EvFrA7jXi1VtxOGt93zjSkWuMQjoOCXVa8ISuMS+UJig==", "compra"=>{"total_bidones"=>"125", "item_compras_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"8"}, "1"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"15", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"9"}, "2"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"20", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"10"}, "3"=>{"cantidad_bidon"=>"80", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"11"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Compra", "id"=>"3"}
  Compra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
  ItemCompra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ? AND "item_compras"."id" IN (8, 9, 10, 11)  [["compra_id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  DELETE FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."id" = ?  [["id", 8]]

  Compra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."id" = ?  [["id", 9]]

  Compra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."id" = ?  [["id", 10]]
  Compra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."id" = ?  [["id", 11]]
  Compra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
   (6.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/compras/3
Completed 302 Found in 164ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
```

**Log luego de dar clic en botón edit y luego en update compra**

```
Started PATCH "/compras/3" for ::1 at 2017-07-17 06:18:50 -0400
Processing by ComprasController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"d2EEkD8dStA+Je+c1NjOXWSfDBbOgRilT
sOp037ibQNazQxFRzxc2biMrkdP1xzyDpFMarXlLGw/JEk4tP63WA==", "compra"=>{"total_bidones"
=>"125"}, "commit"=>"Update Compra", "id"=>"3"}
  Compra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? L
IMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ItemCompra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_c
ompras"."compra_id" = ?  [["compra_id", 3]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "compras" SET "total_bidones" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "com
pras"."id" = ?  [["total_bidones", 0], ["updated_at", "2017-07-17 10:18:50.246957"],
 ["id", 3]]
   (5.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/compras/3
Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)


Started GET "/compras/3" for ::1 at 2017-07-17 06:18:50 -0400
Processing by ComprasController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Compra Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras" WHERE "compras"."id" = ? L
IMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered compras/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 310ms (Views: 306.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

**EDICIÓN N° 3:** Agrego el log de la consola:

```
ItemCompra.last.destroy
  ItemCompra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "item_compras".* FROM "item_compras"  ORDER BY "item_compras"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  DELETE FROM "item_compras" WHERE "item_compras"."id" = ?  [["id", 17]]
   (15.6ms)  commit transaction
=> #<ItemCompra id: 17, cantidad_bidon: 8, compra_id: 5, created_at: "2017-07-21 06:09:30", updated_at: "2017-07-21 06:09:30">
```

**La compra no se actualiza:**

```
Compra.last
  Compra Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "compras".* FROM "compras"  ORDER BY "compras"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Compra id: 5, total_bidones: 8, created_at: "2017-07-21 05:56:06", updated_at: "2017-07-21 06:09:30">
```

Comment: Por favor evita editar la pregunta de tal forma que cambie el alcance de la misma ya que eso invalida las respuestas recibidas. Cuando tengas dudas distintas a la original lo correcto es genersr una pregunta nueva. En tu caso la primer pregunta se resolvió, lo que preguntas ahora es distinto. Lo mejor sería aceptar la respuesta y abrir ina nueva pregunta.

Comment: Por lo pronto ya actualicé mi respuesta para incluir la solución a tu segunda pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...cuando envío el formulario, este no se actualiza, tengo que darle
>   editar nuevamente y enviarlo para que funcione...

Dado que estás utilizando atributos anidados debes guardar los datos **antes** de ejecutar el método `calcula_total_bidones`, por lo que el *callback* que estás buscando es `after_save`.

#### Save/Create/Update

Los *callbacks* de ActiveRecord_ tienen un comportamiento distinto de acuerdo a la acción específica que se esté ejecutando sobre el registro; i.e.  guardando (`*_save`), creando (`*_create`) o actualizando (`*_update`):

- `before_save`, `around_save` y `after_save` se ejecutan en todos los registros, tanto nuevos como  existentes.
- `before_update`, `around_update` y `after_update` se ejecutan únicamente en registros que ya existen.
- `before_create`, `around_create` y `after_create` se ejecutan únicamente en registros nuevos.

> ...al eliminar los elementos `item_compra` desde el formulario de
>   edición de compra, no se actualiza el `total_biones`...

Esto se debe a que `calcula_total_bidones` solo se ejecuta después de guardar un registro en `Compra`; sin embargo, al borrar un registro de `ItemCompra` el registro de `Compra` relacionado no cambia y el método no se ejecuta.

Lo que debes hacer es agregar un *callback* en tu modelo `ItemCompra` para que actualice el registro de `Compra` relacionado después de haber sido borrado; para eso  puedes utilizar el *callback* `after_destroy`, por ejemplo:

```
class ItemCompra < ApplicationRecord
  after_destroy :actualiza_total_bidones

  #...

  private
  def actualiza_total_bidones
    compra  = Compra.find(compra_id)
    bidones = compra.item_compras.map(&:cantidad_bidon).sum
    compra.update_attributes(:total_bidones => bidones)
  end
end
```

Es importante destacar que al borrar elementos **con los métodos `delete` o `delete_all` no se ejecuta *callback* alguno**, por lo que **es necesario utilizar `destroy` o `destroy_all`**<sup>1</sup> para que la solución propuesta funcione.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *`destroy_all` es más lento ya que borra un registro a la vez, en lugar de borrar todos con una misma sentencia* SQL *(que es lo que hace `delete_all`).*</sup>

---

Aunque la solución arriba descrita te debería funcionar sin problemas, te recomendaría analizar tu diseño y utilizar uno distinto; por ejemplo, en lugar de mantener la variable `total_bidones` en `Compra`, podrías calcularla cada vez que necesites obtener dicho total, así te evitas los *callbacks* y simplificas tu código.

Considerando lo anterior, el código de *compras.rb* podría reducirse a:

```
class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :item_compras, :dependent => :destroy

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras, reject_if: RejectDeeplyNested.blank?, allow_destroy: true

 def total_bidones
   item_compras.map(&:cantidad_bidon).sum
 end
end
```

Es todo el código que necesitas para obtener `total_bidones` de cada compra, no es necesario agregar un *callback* en `ItemCompra` (lo cual a mi parecer es más costoso que calcular cada vez).

El método `total_bidones` se comporta como un atributo de `ActiveRecord`, así que lo puedes consultar de la misma forma; por ejemplo:

```
Compra.find(1).total_bidones
```

Comment: Al eliminar un elemento item_compra desde el formulario de compra, no se actualiza el total, solo queda el total anterior.

Comment: Estoy llamando a el método `calcula_total_bidones` que está en el modelo  `compra`  (Deje el método publico, si lo dejo en privado salta un mensaje de error que indica que no puedo acceder a un método privado) desde ItemCompra, pero al eliminar un elemento, este queda con el mismo  `total_bidones` .

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Me imagino que estás borrando con `delete_all`, ¿correcto? `delete`/`delete_all` se brinca los _callbacks_ por lo que debes utilizar `destroy`/`destroy_all`; he actualizado mi respuesta destacar el punto.

Comment: Sí, creo que ese es el problema principal, estoy investigando como utilizar solo destroy/destroy_all

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Te recomiendo que hagas una prueba en consola o en tu controlador para que confirmes el funcionamiento. Ya que lo confirmes entonces actualizas tu aplicación completa.

Comment: Intente con ItemCompra.last, luego con ItemCompra.last.destroy y la cantidad total queda igual, no se actualiza, debería quedar en 0 si no existen ItemCompra para la compra.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo ¿Qué te muestra el log? He intentado reproducir el problema, pero en mi caso si consigo la actualización.

Comment: De la única forma que pude obtener resultados fué creando un  `after_destroy  :actualiza_total_bidones`  `def actualiza_total_bidones
     Compra.find(compra_id).update_attributes(:total_bidones => 0) 
    end `

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Lo que faltaba era salvar el registro después de hacer el `update`, por eso no se veían los cambios; utilizar `update_attributes` es muy buena opción, sin embargo dejarlo fijo en `0` te ocasionará un problema ya que `total_bidones` en la compra asociada **siempre** será `0` una vez que borres un _item_. Por lo tanto, no importará si tienes 5 _items_ más para esa compra, como quiera se mostrará en `0` (lo cual es incorrecto). Checa mi respuesta actualizada con `update_attributes` pero utilizando el cálculo adecuado.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Actualicé nuevamente mi respuesta, agregando una opción que me parece mucho más simple y óptima para lo que estás buscando.